# Как убрать Default File template предупреждение?

Tags: intellij-idea

При инспекции кода класса IDEA выдает предупреждение на подпись в начале файла:

`/** Created by UserName on 10.01.2016*/`:

> Default File template less... (Ctrl+F1)
>   This inspections reports usage of the default file template for File Header.
>   Also, the inspection proposes to change default file template and its usage.

Можно убрать это предупреждение(глаза мозолит), оставив подпись?

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос и опишите как можно подробнее, что за предупреждение вы получаете, при каких условиях и тд.

Comment: Так вынес же в вопросе - выдает предупреждение "Default File template".

Comment: Дело в том, что когда вы сами это видите, вам кажется понятным, о чем вы спрашиваете. Другие люди не видят, то же, что и вы и то о чем вы спрашиваете не так очевидно со стороны. Вопросы нужно писать максимально подробно, чем понятнее вы опишите другим людям, которые ничего не знают о вашей проблеме, что у вас случилось, тем более полезный и быстрый ответ вы получите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предупреждение переводится как :" Измените подпись по умолчанию"

Из этого очевидно, что нужно каким то образом отредактировать подпись, чтобы она отличалась от дефолтной. Для этого щелкните мышью на самой подписи, появится желтая лампочка с возможными вариантами решения проблемы. Выберите "Edit template" в появившемся окошке, исправьте каким то образом подпись, чтобы она отличалась от заданной по умолчанию. Теперь все вновь создаваемые классы не будут выдавать это предупреждение.

[image: screen1]

При этом уже созданные файлы классов придется редактировать вручную, простым исправлением текста.

**UPD** То же самое можно сделать через общие настройки, перед тем, как начинать писать проект :

Идете: File -> Settings... -> Editor -> File and Code Template -> Вкладка:Includes -> В списке слева:File Header

[image: screen]